# Invalid cross-device link Redis

Tags: redis, virtual-machine

I am having an invalid cross-device link error for when Redis rolls its log on a vm.   Both directories are on /tmp/ in the vm and appear to have the same disk.

Is there a way to debug this on a virtual machine?

https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/305

```
Error trying to rename the temporary AOF: Invalid cross-device link
```